# center div tags inside parent div

Tags: html, css

I have two div tags inside a parent div. I want to display the two divs in same line and  centered. Below is the html code.

```
<div id="parent">
    <div id="addEditBtn" style="display:inline-block; vertical-align: middle; width:20px; cursor:pointer;" class="ui-state-default ui-corner-all"> <span class="ui-icon ui-icon-pencil"></span></div>

    <div id="deleteBtn" style="display:inline-block; vertical-align: middle; width:20px; cursor:pointer;" class="ui-state-default ui-corner-all"> <span class="ui-icon ui-icon-trash"></span></div>
</div>
```

I tried with "display:inline-block; vertical-align: middle;" but its getting aligned left. Please help me out to centered the div tags inside the parent div.

Comment: Same line centered? Should they overlap? 
If they have the same size, only the div on Top will be visible!

Answer (score 1):

please add css

```
    #addEditBtn,#deleteBtn {
    display:table;
margin:0 auto;
width:48%;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

When you `display: inline-block;` and element, it is treated like an image or a text character for the purposes of centring.

```
#parent {
    text-align: center;
}
```

See [a live demo](http://jsfiddle.net/JagaP/).

Answer (score 0):

You'll need another level of nested divs.

First level is `inline-block` and `width:50%`, second level is `display:block`, `width:20px` and `margin:0 auto`;

edit :

yeah, `text-align: center` on the parent div should work too : http://jsfiddle.net/ZGeN8/ , but I prefer my answer because it'll be easier to adapt to IE6/7